# Comparing different classes using instanceof

Tags: java, arraylist, instanceof

- Entity.class abstract mother class
- Player.class extends Entity
- Wall.class extends Entity

```
                 public class slkjflksdjf
                 {
                     ArrayList entities = new ArrayList();
                     Player player = new Player();
                     Wall wall = new Wall();

                     public slkjflksdjf()
                     {

                         entities.add(player);
                         entities.add(wall);

                         for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++)
                         {

                             if(entities.get(i) instanceof Wall)
                             {
                                 //do something
                             }

                         }

                     }
                 }
```

When checking instanceof through my actual full size list of entities it's throwing the "do this" block over and over rapidly, in other words playing an audio clip rapidly lol..
so ye from what i can tell it's treating the Wall and Player both as Entity so doing InstanceOf is just causing it to pull a true even if they are all extensions of the Original Entity?

Comment: I could fill this arraylist with like 50 different copies of Floor which also extends Entity and it'll still execute what's in the instanceof block when i know for a fact not everything is the Wall object specifically. Hence why I think it's treating them all as the same thing due to them all extending the Entity class

Comment: Please enter the code text into your question. Then use the "{}" tool to see the text formatted, assuming that it was formatted before. I use three spaces for each level of indentation.

Comment: Or maybe it's treating all Objects as the same on output??

Comment: Post the text of the code. Don't worry about formatting, if you can't fix it.

Comment: however many spaces that is. that's what the formatting wanted behind every line. 14 or so?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors while using your code.

Comment: You won't get errors. It works but not what i would expect it to do.

Comment: When comparing I want it to only say "yes this exists" IF it's a Wall class, though it thinks all are of Wall. instanceof seems to return a true on Wall, Player, Floor classes that it itterates over. I'm assuming because they all extend the same Entity class they are considered the same to the instanceof?

Comment: If some class implements some interface then `SomeClass instanceof UsedInterface` will be `true`

Comment: Also change `ArrayList entities = new ArrayList();` to `ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();`

Comment: in other words i'll just make a seperate copy of the exact same thing named differently in order for wall to be seen as different, thank you that answered my question

Comment: If the Entity class is copied into another class called EntityN and Wall now extends EntityN I've a feeling it might still say true when comparing due to the data in them being the same? I hope that's not how it works

Answer (score 0):

If both Player and Wall extends Entity interaface you can do following:

```
ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
Player player = new Player();
Wall wall = new Wall();

entities.add(0, player);
entities.add(1, wall);

// entities.get(0) instanceof Player is true
// entities.get(0) instanceof Wall is false
// entities.get(0) instanceof Entity is true

// entities.get(1) instanceof Player is false
// entities.get(1) instanceof Wall is true
// entities.get(1) instanceof Entity is true

for(Entity entity : entities) {

  if(entity instanceof Player) {
    // is player
  } else if(entity instanceof Wall) {
    // is wall
  }

}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Helpful if i was trying to select a specific index, I'm not though i'm iterating through the entire list one by one checking if it's a wall when all elements are random index inside of the array meaning i can't just point to the specific index to check

Comment: Thanks for trying though xD

Comment: ooooh inside a forloop just using i as index instead would work i see what you mean

Comment: No need for 2 arrays or 2 interfaces.

Comment: No matter how many times I tried it didn't work still was throwing true. Then i realized I had initialized the player in both my main game loop and again in the startgame so ofc it was throwing true the entire time it was thrown in the 0, 0 coords where there is a tree object existing... Problem solved it seems lol

Comment: I suggest not combining tiles with entities and using 2D arrays for tiles. So that you can easily know (without iterating all tiles) what tiles is for example up from this tile: tile[x][y] and tile[x][y-1]. If you have any further questions about java or optimalizing games you can message me kochamprzygody@gmail.com and/or sent discord link.

Answer (score 0):

If Player is a subclass of Entity and Wall is a subclass of Entity:

player instanceof Entity returns true.

If Wall is a subclass of Entity:

wall instanceof Entity returns true.

However the reverse is not true (.i.e entity instanceof Wall)
Why? Because that is how instanceof operator is defined.

Moreover if Wall and Player are not related (meaning one is not subclass of the other or implementing in case of interfaces).
player instanceof Wall returns false and
wall instanceof Player returns false.